# CloudFormation nested Sub with FindInMap

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

What I'm trying to achieve is resolving variables stored as string in **Mappings**.

```
Mappings:
  Constants: 
    UserDataTest:
      Test: "echo ${NestedVariable}\n"
```

I would like to have it resolved in **UserData**.

```
  UserData: !Base64
    Fn::Join:
      - ''
      - - "#!/bin/bash\n"
        - Fn::Sub: 
          - !FindInMap [Constants, UserDataTest, Test]
          - NestedVariable: xyz
```

Above example wont work as first argument in **Fn::Sub** is expected to be String.

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack
>   operation: Template error: One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions
>   don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string as first argument,
>   and an optional second argument to specify a mapping of values to
>   replace in the string

---

Tried something like this, but it still won't resolve nested variable:

```
 - Fn::Sub: 
   - ${TestValue}
   - { NestedVariable: xyz, TestValue: !FindInMap [Constants, UserDataTest, Test] }
```

Result of this will be:

> echo ${NestedVariable}

---

Also it seemed reasonable to try this way:

```
- Fn::Sub: 
  - Fn::Sub: 
    - ${TestValue}
    - TestValue: !FindInMap [Constants, UserDataTest, Test]
  - NestedVariable: xyz
```

As a result I get the same error as in first example.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this, as the first argument **must be literal string**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c33c28c59c13):

> For the String parameter, you **can't use any functions**. You must specify a string value.